# Building conditional statement across multiple models (CakePHP 1.2.5)

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, join, left-join

Let's say I have 3 models: User, Region, Country.

```
User belongsTo Region
Region belongsTo Country
```

Each of these models is using the Containable behavior.  I'm attempting to find users from the country with code 'US'.  Here's what I'm attempting:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('Country.code' => 'US'),
    'contain'    => array('Region.Country'),
));
```

CakePHP is separating this into 2 queries:

1. First, it is SELECTing the ID's for all countries with code 'US'.
2. Then it is using those ID's to SELECT all users JOINing regions where `region.country_id` is in that list of country ID's previously retrieved.

As a result, I end up with SQL errors in my app since my `conditions` array contains a reference to Country.code, and the second query that Cake builds doesn't JOIN countries.

The best Cake solution I see is to build a sub-query as described in the [Complex Find Conditions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/74/Complex-Find-Conditions) portion of the manual.  However, this seems very convoluted, and is more of a hack than I would like to implement.  Is there an easier way that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nate Abele (former lead dev of CakePHP) wrote an article about doing [ad hoc joins](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/quick-tip-doing-ad-hoc-joins-in-model-find) which might help.

Comment: Cool, I'm going to try this soon...didn't realize 'conditions' array keys (among others, like 'fields' and 'group') could be passed in the contains array.  I'll give the checkmark if it works out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the conditions in the contain as well. E.g:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array('contain' => array(
    'Region' => array(
        'Country' => array(
            'conditions' => array('Country.code' => 'US'),
        ),
    ),
)));
```

See the second-to-last example in [the Containable manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html)